# Do user-played (but JS paused and resumed) youtube videos count as views?

Tags: youtube-api

The [iframe docs for embedded YouTube videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) are pretty clear:

> **Note:** A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if
>   it is initiated via a native play button in the player.

But does anyone know if a video which has *once* met that criteria, then both paused and later resumed by JavaScript, count as a view?

---

For context, I'd like to do something kinda like youtube-doubler, but I really want the views to count.  In many cases I believe my theoretical-users will want the same, and be happy to click on both videos.  Is this possible?

(I wholly understand YouTube may change their mind on this, but I can't find this info anywhere.  Even if I end up experimenting and figuring it out myself, I'll keep this question up so it might come up in search results)

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't explicitly state how it's doing the view counts so there's no really precise way to answer this question. All we know is what's stated in [How views are counted](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785?hl=en):

**How views are counted**

> We want to make sure that videos are being viewed by actual humans and
>   not computer programs. During the first couple of hours after a video
>   has been published, we'll only show views that our systems believe to
>   be valid. This might not yet show all legitimate views at that time.
>
> After quality views are counted, view count updates more frequently.
>   The process of including all quality views can take some time
>   depending on a video's popularity and viewership. Afterward, the view
>   count updates more frequently, but keep in mind that we're constantly
>   validating views, so view count can always be adjusted.

**Check views with YouTube Analytics**

> If you're looking at a video you uploaded, you can monitor your views
>   more closely using YouTube Analytics. However, keep in mind that the
>   Realtime report only shows estimates of potential view activity and
>   might not match the number you see on the watch page.

TL:DR, I don't think you can validate if your proposed method works.